Filter out OpenTelemetry traces that has no logs
I have this very simple standard Weather Api example controller where I've enabled OpenTelemetry:
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

var Builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
Builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Warning);

// Add services to the container.
_ = Sdk
    .CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
    .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
    .AddConsoleExporter()
    .Build();

Builder.Services.AddControllers();

var App = Builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
App.MapControllers();
App.Run();

As I've set the minimum logging level to warning, I don't see any logs printed in the console. But if I call the Weather API endpoint, OpenTelemetry still creates and prints a trace to the console window:
Activity.TraceId:            1d2d6b56be7a8051011388a35cf5f993
Activity.SpanId:             6a3ada20893b840c
Activity.TraceFlags:         Recorded
Activity.DisplayName:        GET WeatherForecast
Activity.Kind:               Server
Activity.StartTime:          2024-12-03T12:26:43.2111251Z
Activity.Duration:           00:00:00.0670580
Activity.Tags:
    server.address: localhost
    server.port: 5214
    http.request.method: GET
    url.scheme: http
    url.path: /WeatherForecast
    network.protocol.version: 1.1
    user_agent.original: PostmanRuntime/7.43.0
    http.route: WeatherForecast
    http.response.status_code: 200
Instrumentation scope (ActivitySource):
    Name: Microsoft.AspNetCore
Resource associated with Activity:
    telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
    telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
    telemetry.sdk.version: 1.10.0
    service.name: unknown_service:Test.Asp.Net

Is there a way to disable this behavior? If the trace is empty (i.e. no logs associated with the trace), I would ideally like the trace to not be created and thus not printed.

I think there's a lot of misunderstanding here. Traces and Logs are independent things. The trace isn't empty here, the span/Activity has attributes associated with it. Log Levels are to do with log data, there is no similar concept in tracing.

I will admit that my knowledge of OpenTelemetry might be lacking at times, but my point still stands. If a call to my endpoint is made, and the execution of the endpoint produces no logs, I don't want a trace or span either. Currently it produces a lot of noise in the telemetry that's unnecessary if there are no logs I need to track for the endpoint call.

They're different signals and not related, so that isn't something you can do.

I suppose a better way to phrase that is that a trace doesn't "have" logs. Your question would be "if no logs are created first an ASP.NET Core request, how do I stop an Activity being created". Which isn't possible as the activity is created at the start of the request and has no knowledge of whether the request will generate some logs.

OK, I get what you're saying. If we can't stop traces from being created due the activity being created, it's also fine if the trace isn't pushed to the collector. But I just don't know enough to understand how to achieve this.
The end goal is, that if nothing interesting happened, then I don't need the trace either. Both traces and logs take up bandwidth when pushed to the collector.

The idea in otel is that you do that in the collector itself. You can run that as a sidecar, or on the same node, which will allow you to reduce that data.  The concept you should look into is Sampling (Head and Tail), that's the way to achieve dropping data that matches criteria, but that isn't based on the logs, it's based on the data in the Activity.

@MartinDotNet if the OP wants to implement a kind of black-box logging, ie use all spans+logs in a trace if it fails, how could the implement it using tail sampling? I suspect that's what the actual question is here. Log4net could do something similar, eg send an email with the last 100 logs in case of an Error event.

I'm not sure of ak approach that doesn't involve relying on logs marking something on the trace, they're entirely separate and correlated by an attribute, the collector doesn't combine the signals.

I could of course introduce some code that could mark spans (System.Diagnostic.Activity) with some additional information whether we want to keep or discard them, but that still leaves the fact that I have to use tail sampling to ensure spans aren't exported as soon as they're created. Not sure how I would go about doing that in the OpenTelemetry SDK.

I wasn't really satisfied with the answers so far, so eventually I stumbled upon my own solution. I don't know if it's the "right" way to do things, but I'm still providing it as an answer in case it helps others.
I found out that the SDK actually supports filtering out traces that we want to export for an Activity by resetting the Recorded flag:
Activity.ActivityTraceFlags &= ~ActivityTraceFlags.Recorded;

Thus, it's possible to add a Processor before the Exporter that can filter out traces we don't want to export.
However, traces and logs aren't correlated. Processors for traces doesn't have access to logs. So I made a general solution by taking into account that logs would always be produced before traces are ended, and ended up with the following solution:
internal interface ITelemetryFiltering
{
    Int32 GetNumLogsForTrace(ActivityTraceId TraceId);
    void IncrementTraceLogs(ActivityTraceId TraceId);
    void TraceFinished(ActivityTraceId TraceId);
}

internal class TelemetryFiltering: ITelemetryFiltering
{
    private readonly Dictionary<ActivityTraceId, Int32> _NumLogsForTrace = [];

    public void IncrementTraceLogs(ActivityTraceId TraceId)
    {
        ref var NumLogs = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(_NumLogsForTrace, TraceId, out _);
        NumLogs++;
    }

    public void TraceFinished(ActivityTraceId TraceId) => _NumLogsForTrace.Remove(TraceId);
    public Int32 GetNumLogsForTrace(ActivityTraceId TraceId) => _NumLogsForTrace.TryGetValue(TraceId, out var Value) ? Value : 0;
}

internal sealed class LogFilteringProcessor: BaseProcessor<LogRecord>
{
    private readonly ITelemetryFiltering _TelemetryFiltering;
    public LogFilteringProcessor(ITelemetryFiltering TelemetryFiltering) => _TelemetryFiltering = TelemetryFiltering;
    public override void OnEnd(LogRecord Data) => _TelemetryFiltering.IncrementTraceLogs(Data.TraceId);
}

internal sealed class TraceFilteringProcessor: BaseProcessor<Activity>
{
    private readonly ITelemetryFiltering _TelemetryFiltering;
    public TraceFilteringProcessor(ITelemetryFiltering TelemetryFiltering) => _TelemetryFiltering = TelemetryFiltering;

    public override void OnEnd(Activity Activity)
    {
        if (_TelemetryFiltering.GetNumLogsForTrace(Activity.TraceId) == 0)
        {
            // Bypass export
            Activity.ActivityTraceFlags &= ~ActivityTraceFlags.Recorded;
        }
        _TelemetryFiltering.TraceFinished(Activity.TraceId);
    }
}

Then we just add the Processors to the Trace and Logging builder:
TelemetryFiltering TelemetryFiltering = new();

var TracingBuilder = Sdk
    .CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
    .AddProcessor(new TraceFilteringProcessor(TelemetryFiltering)) // Add processor before exporter
    .AddOtlpExporter(ConfigureOtlpExporterOptions);

_ = LoggingBuilder
    .AddOpenTelemetry(Logging =>
    {
        _ = Logging
            .AddProcessor(new LogFilteringProcessor(TelemetryFiltering)) // Add processor so we can correlate logs to traces
            .AddOtlpExporter(ConfigureOtlpExporterOptions);
    });

So again, I can't say if there is a better way to do it, but it was the only way I could find.

This is not the right way. MartinDotNet is one of the best speakers and authors on OTEL in the .NET space so you should listen to him. Traces and logs are independent things, exported by different exporters, possibly to different services (eg Elastic, Jaeger and Prometheus). Instead of trying to filter traces, make sure logs and traces can be correlated. If you check the .NET Aspire Starter sample you'll see you can move from logs to traces and back because they're correlated correctly.

Right now you're mangling the traces based on the incorrect mental model you got from the console. The Console exporters are not a good way of visualizing OTEL. The .NET Aspire dashboard on the other hand visualizes logs, traces and metrics all together and allows you to move between them. I'd suggest (strongly) to use the standalone .NET Aspire dashboard as the target of both traces and logs, to see what's really going on.

Even the assumption logs would always be produced before traces is wrong due to log buffering.

I do appreciate all the feedback I get. I admit this is a workaround, but I DID test this with the Aspire.net dashboard. I used a Console exporter here to make the example as simple as possible. Running a sidecar is not something I want to do, and besides, it does not solve the issue that logs and traces arrive at different times. The workaround I proposed seems to work. I have verified that any call to Log will invoke the processor, and since log calls are always done before a trace ends, it should work. I believe logs and traces are buffered before sent to a collector, but not the processor.

But I'm open to other suggestions or any other feedback on how to discard traces if there are no logs with that trace id.

Think about what you asked: A Trace, which has a TraceID, is the overall session, not a single entry. Spans are the single entries. The TraceId is generated when a new trace starts and the first Span is sent, so by definition there won't be any log events with that TraceID. After it starts, and if you enrich the log entries with the TraceID, you'll get logs with that TraceID. If you do what you want, you'll lose all spans until the first log entry and get all spans until the trace's end. You won't be able to make sense of the trace.

To do what you want you'd need to buffer a trace's spans in the collector (or processor) until you got a signal that said you should emit them. You want to use a log for this but frankly, that could be a special span as well. In any case, this is called tail sampling and is already supported by the OTEL Collector, various services and (rarely) service-side processors. You could use this as a short of "black box" to gather complete traces when an error occurs and only partial traces for "good" cases

If you want a black box though, the easiest solution would be to check for a failed trace or span, not an error log. If your application code takes care to mark the Activity as failed instead of just logging an error, it would be easy for a processor to buffer traces and logs up to a point and emit them if the trace fails. The collector (or a service like Elastic/OpenSearch) could do the same

I am learning new things about OTEL every day. I realize now that my workaround only works if the entire trace is finished before the export has a chance to export it to the collector, i.e. it fails if the code takes too long. Trail sampling does indeed sound like something I'd like, but I would also need something similar to logs. It it wasn't clear, I am currently using the OpenTelemetry SDK nuget package.

Check Martin's talks and tutorials. He's good - I know because I invited him to talk to Devoxx Greece 2023, a Java conference and he still rocked it, filling the largest auditorium

The issue with this approach is that you're not talking about a trace, but an individual span. A single request will have multiple spans that make up the trace.  E.g. a you might have 15 database calls, each is a span. Those will "finish" and be sent to the exporter before the request has finished, and you might have logs appearing after that which mean you want it.
